# How do I configure ImageView to display subrect of bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I have a view that contains an ImageView. The ImageView is populated with a png resource, and fills the width and height of the image view.

Instead of this configuration, I would like to display the image zoomed in by an arbitrary percentage, and translated by an arbitrary coordinate. My question is, how can I configure an image view to display a sub-region of it's src bitmap, with arbitrary translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with matrix [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

1. Make a ImageView to have matrix scaleType, `android:scaleType="matrix"`
2. Create and manipulate a [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) like this,

   `Matrix matrix = new Matrix();`
   `matrix.postTranslate(-10, -10);`
   `matrix.postScale(2, 2);`
3. set this matrix to ImageView, `imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix)`